# Cannot read property aDataSort . DataTable bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I just start to learn about `bootstrap` and creating a simple project that can show a data into `DataTable` but I am having this error `Cannot read property aDataSort of undefined`

*Feel Free to edit my code if i got it wrong*

These are my code

**JS**

```
var globalPersonId = 1;
var dataTablesOrderedList = "";
$(document).ready(function () {

    var dataTablesFirstBS = $('#dataTables-FIrstSample').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        info: true,
        search: true,
        sort: false,
        stateSave: true,
        order: [[1, "asc"], [2, "asc"]],
        lengthMenu: [[50, 100, 200, -1], [50, 100, 200, "All"]],
        ajax: { "url": "/BS/GetFirstDataTable" },
        columns:
        [
            { data: "BSId", title: "", visible: false, searchable: false, sortable: false },
            { data: "Name", title: "Name", sClass: "alignCenter", sortable: false }
        ]
    });

MyFirstBS();
    function MyFirstBS() {

        dataTablesOrderedList = $('#tblMyFirstBS').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            info: true,
            retrieve: true,
            destroy: true,
            search: true,
            sort: false,
            stateSave: true,
            lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
            ajax: {
                "url": "/BS/GetFirstDataTable",
                "data": function (d) {
                    d.BSId = globalPersonId;
                }
            },
            columns:
        [
            { data: "BSId", title: "", visible: false, searchable: false, sortable: false },
            { data: "Name", title: "Name",  searchable: false, sortable: false }
        ]
        });
    }


});
```

**Controller**

```
 public JsonResult GetFirstDataTable()
    {

        var Data = new List<object>();

        Data = db.FirstBS.Where(x => x.BSId == x.BSId)
        .Select(t =>
            new
            {
                BSId = t.BSId,
                Name = t.Name
            }).ToList<object>();
        return gf.DataTableAjaxHandlerClientSide(Data);
    }
```

Comment: i think you need to set `sortable: false` for all the columns defined under `#tblMyFirstBS` `DataTable`. Please try that and let me know.

Comment: @vijayP i set it in `dataTablesFirstBS columns` I also set it in my function?.

Comment: i don't see it in `function MyFirstBS()`. Can you please modify your question.

Comment: @vijayP sorry typo. Do I need to set in my function?

Comment: yes. Also from where you are calling this ` MyFirstBS()`?

Comment: @vijayP I modify it a bit. I call my function inside my document ready for the 1st load.

Comment: @vijayP I solve it now :)

Answer (score 1):

i solved that problem in my case by removing the order line

```
order: [[ 7, "desc" ]],
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by removing the second order here is my new order now

```
order: [[1, "asc"]],
```